# Make chrome extension capable of querying browser page's window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension.

I would like to be able to access the underlying browser page's window object, basically at-will.

I don't directly control the page in question, so I need some way to inject a script into the DOM, which will respond with the `window` object whenever it's queried.

I want to do this in a cleaner fashion than just stringifying a function and injecting it as a `<script>` into the DOM.

Is there a clean, standard way to do this?

I have tried to follow the instructions in http://waitingphoenix.com/how-to-make-your-chrome-extension-access-webpage/

but I cannot get a GET_DUCK event to fire anywhere.

Comment: Don't content scripts already have this ability?

Comment: I don't think so? Everything I've googled says that the extension can't access page variables directly and instead has to communicate with the page.

Comment: Right, I was thinking of `document`.

Comment: In Chrome the only way is using a script element, see the linked topic for examples and methods of communication. In Firefox you can use wrappedJSObject to access the page context directly, see MDN site if needed.